# Question regarding submanifolds of submanifolds

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

The statement I want to show is

> Suppose $r\ge 1$, $M_2$ be a $C^r$-submanifold of $M_3$, and $M_1$ be subset of $M_2$. Then $M_1$ is a $C^r$-submanifold of $M_3$ iff it is a $C^r$-submanifold of $M_2$.

I tried to give a proof ($\alpha_i$ is the differential structure of $M_i$):

**Proof.** Assume $M_1$ is a $C^r$-submanifold of $M_3$. Then for all $x\in M_1$, there exists $(\phi_3,U_3)\in\alpha^3_r$ such that $M_1\cap U_3=\phi_3^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^n\times\{0\})$. **Since $M_2$ is a $C^r$-submanifold of $M_3$, $\phi_3|_{M_2\cap U_3}$ is a chart of $M_2$**,
$$
M_1\cap(M_2\cap U_3)=\phi_3|_{M_2}^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^n\times\{0\})
$$
therefore $M_1$ is a submanifold of $M_2$. For the other direction, if $M_1$ is a $C^r$-submanifold of $M_2$, then for all $x\in M_1$, there exists $(\phi_2,U_2)\in\alpha^2_r$ such that $M_1\cap U_2=\phi_2^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^n\times\{0\})$. Since $M_2$ is a $C^r$-submanifold of $M_3$, **there exists $(\phi_3,U_3)\in\alpha^3_r$ such that $\phi_2=\phi_3|_{M_2\cap U_3}$**, then
$$
M_1\cap U_3=\phi_3(\mathbb{R}^n\times\{0\})
$$
thus $M_1$ is indeed a submanifold of $M_3$.

However after checking I find out that the bolded statements are flawed. I tried to fix the proof but I am stuck. I want to know whether my proof can be fixed and whether there is a better way to show this statement.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think a better way is to use the fact that a, immersed/embedded submanifold is characterized as being the image of an immersion/embedding. Try to work with $\iota\colon M_1\to M_2$, $\iota_2\colon M_2 \to M_3$, and $\iota = \iota_2\circ \iota_1 \colon M_1 \to M_3$.

Comment: If $M_1$ is a submanifold of $M_2$ and $M_2$ is a submanifold of $M_3$, then since $\iota=\iota_2\circ\iota_1$ is still a injective immersion and homeomorphic to its image, $\iota$ is an embedding and therefore $M_1$ is a submanifold. On the other hand, if $M_1$ is a submanifold of $M_3$ and $M_2$ is a submanifold of $M_3$, suppose the embeddings $\iota_1:M_1\to M_3$ and $\iota_2:M_2\to M_3$, then $\iota_2|_{M_2}^{-1}\circ\iota_1$ is an embedding from $M_1$ to $M_2$. Is this argument right? I doubt i made some mistakes since it seemed almost too easy. @Didier

Comment: I think the argument is good! Differential geometry is a powerful language, and once things are written in this language, they are (sometimes...) short and neat